# read huge .csv file in pandas (90GB) amd chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I know there had been many topics regarding panda and chunks to read a csv file but I still suffer to manage to read a huge csv file.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6

data = {}
count = 0
project_IDs = set()
count_analysed = 0


for chunk in pd.read_csv(path_source, iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize, header=None, delimiter=",", usecols=[0,1], names=["project_id","commit_id"]):
    for row in list(chunk.values):
        count_analysed += 1
        if str(row[0]) in project_IDs:
            data[str(row[1])] = 0


    cnt += 1
```

The idea is to store the data temporarly in sets for better performance

My PC has 16GB of RAM. Working with SSD.

I always get the memory error. Any idea what I can do to read this csv file?

Comment: Are you actually trying to for loop through that whole file? The idea behind `pandas` is that you don't have to but can use a vectorised approach.

Comment: Okay tthanks for the comment. Havent worked with verorised approach yet not sure if this works for my data. - The thing is the csv files runs against an json file to only write the necessary data that I need to a new json. I hope this is kind of clear.